# adding columns in mat-table without effecting the previos column data

Tags: angular

I need to add new columns for mat-table which is already there and mat-table is getting data from the service and i need to add new column data manually without affecting the previous data.

```
displayedColumns: string[] = [
 'actions',
 'vbId',
 'lvea',
 'programRegionBuild',
 'modelYear',
 'vehicleCode',
 'ivsModelYear',
 'ivsVehicleCode',
 'regionSaleCode'
];
```

columns need to be added are.

```
LVEA,
IVS Vehical Code,
IVS MY,
PSC Range,
UP Range,
FDJ Range,
DC Range,
PEC Range,
TT Range,
PP Range
MP1 Range,
J1 Range.
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatsoever columns are needed buy you needs to be mentioned under the

```
displayedColumns: string[] = [];
```

Else your table will throw error for unspecified column names since, your mat table contains definition for columns to be rendered under

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
```